# boost_multi_index iterator dereference gives const

Tags: c++, boost-multi-index

This is related to dereference boost_multi_index hashed_index iterator. Please see the code below:

```
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::multi_index;
using Container = boost::multi_index_container<
    std::string,
    indexed_by<hashed_unique<const_mem_fun<std::string, size_t, &std::string::size>>>>;

Container container;
auto& hash_map = container.get<0>();
auto[it, inserted] = hash_map.insert("1234");
if (!inserted)
    *it = "1234";
```

Which gives:

```
error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'const value_type {aka const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'const char [5]')
         *it = "1234";
               ^~~~~~
```

So, looks like it is possible to call only const methods on the object referenced by iterator `it`.

1. Why is it done in this way? (Is it for container to be able to track *all* the changes?)
2. Is there better/another way to write to the referenced object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boost.MultiIndex iterators are const (won't give you non-const access to the element) because otherwise values could be changed without the owning `multi_index_container` knowing, which would result in elements being mispositioned, undefined behavior, etc. This is the same situation as iterators in a `std::set`, for instance.

To modify an element, there are various facilities discussed [here](https://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating). Note that the documentation is pre-C++11 and does not mention the use of lambda expressions in combination with `modify`, which would look like:

```
hash_map.modify(it,[](std::string& x){x="1234";});
```